# How to get a one-key shortcut for full screening an Application (not just maximize)

Tags: applescript

In Windows there is the ubiquitous F11 functionality which on the Mac is done by ctrl-cmd-F. As far as I found there is no universal way to get a one-key shortcut. It should be possible to do with Applescript and Alfred 3. Anybody well-versed in this to set it up? Or did I forget a simpler method?

Comment: Can you not go into System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > and set up a one-key shortcut for full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*System Preferences* lets you change builtin menu shortcuts to almost anything you like.  This screen shot is from macOS 10.13 (High Sierra):

[image: System Preferences in macOS]

Here, you can see that I've created a shortcut under the **All Applications** heading, so any application that contains the particular menu item that takes its window to full screen will adopt the new shortcut.

The name of the menu item—which must be entered *exactly*, including capitalisation—is **Enter Full Screen**.  As you know, its default shortcut is 
<kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, but here I've changed it to just the equals sign key, <kbd>=</kbd>.

If you try to establish a new shortcut to be a single key, you'll often be denied by *Finder*'s beep, alerting you to an invalid command or value.  The trick to circumvent this when creating these shortcuts in *System Preferences* is to hold down <kbd>Fn</kbd> and press the desired key, which will then be accepted.

You'll want to create a second shortcut to take your application out of fullscreen and into normal mode again.  This menu item is called **Exit Full Screen**, and by default, shares the same shortcut as its cousin, therefore it makes sense that your new shortcut should be the same as the one you set to **Enter Full Screen** also.

With the setup in place as depicted by my screenshot, a single tap of my <kbd>=</kbd> key takes me fullscreen; and another tap takes me back out into normal view.  Cleverly, testing this in *Safari*, it **doesn't** respond to this shortcut whilst I'm typing in this text box, which is how I am still able to print an equals sign, =.  Once I leave the text box and the focus returns to a non-input element of the *Safari* window, the shortcut becomes active again.  I haven't tested to see whether this neat feature applies to other applications.  I suspect it will work for some, and won't for others.

Comment: Also works on Mojave.